# Can I put a non-static object in a static property?

Tags: php, oop, symfony

Can I do this?

```
class A {
    public function foo() { echo "whatever";}
}
class B {
    static public $var;
    static function initVar($var) { self::$var = $var; }
    static public function bar() { return self::$var->foo(); }
}
class C {
    public function baz() {
        $a = new A();
        B::initVar($a);
        echo B::bar(); // should print "whatever"
    }
}
```

if not, is there any way to a static method to access an given object instance ?

Comment: Do you have PHP set up anywhere? Then try it. Let it show you all errors and warnings and you'll know, if you can do this or not

Comment: Yes you pass it the instance....

Comment: Apart from `static initVar` should be a function, I don't see why not.

Comment: Online testing tools [without saving](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and [this one](http://codepad.viper-7.com/) saves the result. Check [this example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/hWqfkv) using your code.

Comment: You have missed `function` keyword between `static initVar` and `new $A();` should be `new A();` or `new A;`.

Comment: Indeed, I made the mistakes above when I posted the question.I have corrected the original question. Yet, when I try to do this in my actual code in symfony I get the "call to a member function info() on a non-object" error. Debugged it and get_class returns the correct class. Ideas ?

Comment: actual code: http://pastebin.com/f5pNbQJ1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. This is usually how Singleton (a pattern where a object only should be instantiated once) is implemented. Though this pattern is considered bad...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Example (though within the same class...):

```
class A
{
   private static $inst;
   public static function instance()
   {
        if (self::$inst === NULL)
        {
            self::$inst = new A();
        }
        return self::$inst;
   }
   /* constructor etc */
}

$a = A::instance();
$a->someMethod();

?>
```